# Finding local minima and maxima in a scanned ECG using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to process a  scanned ECG image  using matlab(I'm a complete novice). I'd like to:-
   1.find and highlight all local maxima and minima in the ECG
2.compute and display the distance between the successive minima and maxima 
I'm using a jpeg image  from the internet .After converting it to grayscale ,I'm at a loss for what to do .I've  tried the functions in
[How can I find local maxima in an image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856197/how-can-i-find-local-maxima-in-an-image-in-matlab)
http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/58002-how-to-find-local-maxima-and-minima-of-a-noisy-ecg
but the image retains the non-maxima and non-minima points.Will converting 
Any help in this(or advice on how I could better myself at matlab ) would be much appreciated .

Comment: Could you describe the problem a bit more in detail? In particular, what the problem is when you apply the found solutions?

Comment: I'd like to get something like [this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRrY4lzmj7awsoqsuqlghvXbR59DpcpNpF5K8z2jA6-RBx48Mt_w)but imregionalmax() and others are not giving me the 3 peaks I need in the image .How do I process the image to get those?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Eridanus include at least a representative input image and what output you expect from it.

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to be searching for spikes in the signal I would recommend the following:

Suppose you have a vector called `signal`

```
treshold = std(signal); %Multiply with a constant to get a nice result
peak = signal>mean(signal) + treshold;
dip = signal>mean(signal) - treshold;
```

This can give you the location of all spikes if the signal is always at roughly the same level, otherwise you need to run this on a part of the signal instead of the full signal.

After you have the locations of the peaks and dips it should not be too hard to analyse them.

Comment: Thanks,Will definitely try.

Answer (score 1):

To get the local minima of an image I :

```
minima=I(1:end-2,2:end-1)>I(2:end-1,2:end-1) && I(3:end,2:end-1)>I(2:end-1,2:end-1) && I(2:end-1,1:end-2)>I(2:end-1,2:end-1) && I(2:end-1,3:end)>I(2:end-1,2:end-1);
```

Thus you get a matrix with 1 on minima and 0 on none minima( Note that the border are removed)

To get minima list of x and y

```
[x,y]=find(minima);
x=x+1;y=y+1; %Adding the removed border
```

To get minima values:

```
J=I(2:end-1,2:end-1);
val=J(minima(:));
```

For your second question I don't understand what you want